# Merging data in Pandas with different column titles

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to utilise pandas to tidy up some prescribing information I have been given. 2 practices have recently merged, but the data is given for each practice individually. I want to merge all this data, remove the 2 practices from the data frame, and replace them with a single new name of the merged practice.

I currently have this,

```
PracticeName    Items     Cost       
Practice A       1500     24000
Practice B       1300     22500
Practice C       900      15000
```

I would like to merge practice A and C to get

```
PracticeName    Items     Cost       
Practice AC      2400     39000
Practice B       1300     22500
```

The actual file is much larger than this with 100s of drugs listed for each practice.

I have so far managed to add the 2 columns together by using `groupby` and then using the `sum()` method but this involved adding an extra column in the original csv file. Which isn't ideal. It also only brought back the new column I had grouped on and didnt change the actual practice name.

Is there a better way to group the 2 practices A and C together and then get the sum of their items and cost and then return that as a new practice name practice AC?

Comment: Why not just remove the extra-column after the groupby?

Comment: The full CSV has 70 practices on there, I need to merge these 2 practices which are now just a single practice so that I can calculate their total spend and more in-depth analysis of their cost per patient.

Comment: You havent really answered the my question though

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you meant remove practice B in the example I made... I dont really want to make a new column in the CSV file. I would like to just import it and then merge the data in the 2 rows. I am going to have to do quite a few spreadsheets and adding that column each time on the CSV first would be a little tedious

Comment: You dont have to write the extra-column to your csv files. You can remove the extra-column from the data-frame after your groupby operation is done

Comment: Sorry I am very new to pandas and working my way through an udemy course. So if I have the 3 columns as in my example. How can I group Practice A and C? I have only learnt to group them if they have a column name such as `newpractice = df.groupBy('PracticeName')` Is there a way to pick two values from the column to group together? such as `newPractice = df.groupby('Practice A', 'Practice B') I know this exact line wouldnt work as the groupby method expects a column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the relevant practices, rename them and only then use the groupby. `isin` checks if the practices names are in the choices we put in the expression.

```
cond = df["PracticeName"].isin(["Practice A", "Practice C"])

df.loc[cond, "PracticeName"] = "Practice AC"

df.groupby("Practice Name").sum()
```

Here is a short example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng() # random numbers and picking choices

n = 20
prac = rng.choice(["Practice A", "Practice B", "Practice C"], n)
items = rng.integers(1, 5, n)
cost = rng.integers(10, 20, n)
other_items = rng.integers(4, 15, n)
other_costs = rng.integers(9, 18, n)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "PracticeName": prac,
    "items": items,
    "cost": cost,
    "other_items": other_items,
    "other_costs": other_costs
})

cond = df["PracticeName"].isin(["Practice A", "Practice C"])

df.loc[cond, "PracticeName"] = "Practice AC"
df.groupby("PracticeName").sum()
```

The original dataframe looks similar to this :

```
   PracticeName  items  cost  other_items  other_costs
0    Practice B      3    13            9           13
1    Practice A      3    18            9           11
2    Practice B      4    15            7           12
3    Practice B      1    16            6           10
4    Practice A      3    13           11           10
5    Practice B      3    19            9           17
6    Practice B      1    17           10           10
7    Practice C      2    11            7            9
8    Practice C      1    17           13           14
9    Practice B      3    13           11           17
10   Practice C      1    10            4           16
11   Practice A      3    16           12           14
12   Practice C      4    19            5           17
13   Practice C      4    10            7           13
14   Practice B      1    16           12           14
15   Practice B      1    15            6            9
16   Practice C      3    10            6            9
17   Practice C      3    17            4           17
18   Practice B      1    15           13           17
19   Practice B      3    12            7           12
```

and ends up looking like this :

```
              items  cost  other_items  other_costs
PracticeName                                       
Practice AC      27   141           78          130
Practice B       21   151           90          131
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m=df.PracticeName=='Practice B'
df3=df[m].append(df[~m].iloc[:,-2:].groupby(df[~m].PracticeName.str.replace('(\s\D+)','AC')).sum(0).reset_index())
print(df3)




 PracticeName  Items   Cost
1   Practice B   1300  22500
0   PracticeAC   2400  39000
```

How it Works

```
#Filter out B

m=df.PracticeName=='Practice B'



#Mask those that are not b and eliminate first column
   df[~m].iloc[:,-2:]

#For those that are not B replace the space after Practice and the following Alpha with AC or those you need to combine

df[~m].PracticeName.str.replace('(\s\D+)','AC')

#Now use the two seteps above to create new datframe in a groupby process

    df[~m].iloc[:,-2:].groupby(df[~m].PracticeName.str.replace('(\s\D+)','AC')).sum(0).reset_index())

#Append the new datframe from the process above to a daframe that has filtered out those elements you dint want to combine

df3=df[m].append(df[~m].iloc[:,-2:].groupby(df[~m].PracticeName.str.replace('(\s\D+)','AC')).sum(0).reset_index())
```

Comment: @James Smith see my answer and the steps. Happy to help you understand if needed. Let me know if there are any issues.